# mail rejected with error 421 connection rate limit exceeded

Tags: email, debian, sendmail

I am running debian jessie with sendmail 8.14.4. I do not find where is the setting to disable the mails to be rejected for a certain host and i get periodically this message:

```
May 28 16:20:30 mx6 sm-mta[14808]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=[x.x.x.x], arg2=x.x.x.x, relay=[x.x.x.x], reject=421 4.3.2 Connection rate limit exceeded
```

I have removed from sendmail.mc the configuration

define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE',`15')dnl
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_WINDOW_SIZE',`60s')dnl

still the messages are rejected which I do not understand because those option would delay the messages and not reject them.

is there a way to disable for certain domains that there is no connection limit at all?  need to recompile? downgrade? I am using sendmail installed via apt-get.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/mail/access write lines like this:

```
ClientRate: x.x.x.x 0
```

where x.x.x.x is the IP you want to be **not** rate limited. Than refresh the access.db like this:

```
makemap hash /etc/mail/access.db < /etc/mail/access
```

Comment: There should be no space after ClientRate:.